# Ruby gem for Rails app: how to get `Rails.env` method without requiring Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have RoR experience, but I'm working on my first gem.

The gem is specifically for use in Rails apps and I want to rely on `Rails.env` in several cases.

I know requiring Rails in the `.gemspec` is a bad idea (at least bad practice) because Rails is big and comes with lots of its own dependencies.

But `Rails.env` isn't exactly an extension I can just pull in.

`Rails.env` functionality comes from [`railties`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04972d9b9ef60796dc8f0917817b5392d61fcf09/railties/lib/rails.rb#L72) which itself relies on `active_support`, `action_dispatch` and a bunch of other things:

```rb
require "rails/ruby_version_check"

require "pathname"

require "active_support"
require "active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting"
require "active_support/core_ext/module/delegation"
require "active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options"
require "active_support/core_ext/object/blank"

require "rails/application"
require "rails/version"

require "active_support/railtie"
require "action_dispatch/railtie"

module Rails
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
  extend ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable

  autoload :Info
  autoload :InfoController
  autoload :MailersController
  autoload :WelcomeController

  class << self
    ...

    # Returns the current Rails environment.
    #
    #   Rails.env # => "development"
    #   Rails.env.development? # => true
    #   Rails.env.production? # => false
    def env
      @_env ||= ActiveSupport::EnvironmentInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"].presence || ENV["RACK_ENV"].presence || "development")
    end
```

`ActiveSupport::EnvironmentInquirer` just gives me the ability to do `Rails.env.production?` which I don't really care about.

I could also just mimic this behavior by checking for `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` and `ENV["RACK_ENV"]` but if `Rails.env` is changed, that doesn't change the `ENV` variables:

```
3.0.2 :001 > Rails.env
 => "development" 
3.0.2 :005 > ENV["RAILS_ENV"]
 => "development" 
3.0.2 :006 > ENV["RACK_ENV"]
 => "development" 
3.0.2 :007 > Rails.env = 'test'
 => "test" 
3.0.2 :008 > Rails.env
 => "test" 
3.0.2 :009 > ENV["RAILS_ENV"]
 => "development" 
3.0.2 :010 > ENV["RACK_ENV"]
 => "development"
```

Or I could just instantiate the class as a PORO, but this also seems like bad practice:

```rb
module Rails
  def self.env
    @_env ||=
      ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||
      ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||
      'development'
  end
end
```

Right now I'm just rescuing when `Rails` throws a name error:

```rb
@environment =
  begin
    Rails.env
  rescue NameError
    'development'
  end
```

Is there a standard way to accomplish this or is my `rescue` the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`defined?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-defined-3F) to check whether a top-level constant `Rails` is defined:

```
def rails_env
  ::Rails.env if defined?(::Rails)
end
```

if you want to be extra safe:

```
def rails_env
  ::Rails.env if defined?(::Rails) && ::Rails.respond_to?(:env)
end
```

To enforce a plain string: (instead of a [`ActiveSupport::EnvironmentInquirer`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/environment_inquirer.rb) instance)

```
def rails_env
  ::Rails.env.to_s if defined?(::Rails) && ::Rails.respond_to?(:env)
end
```

With the above you could write:

```
@environment = rails_env || 'development'
```

Comment: Well answered, and I appreciate the escalation of safety in your answers.